# Binding Mode Efficiency

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, binding, binding-mode

What's the difference between:

```
{Binding Prop, Mode=OneTime}
```

and

```
 {Binding Prop, Mode=OneWay}
```

I assume there's a difference in the efficiency. Can anyone describe how binding mode works or give some reference to some info about this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

as per [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx),

`OneTime` updates the target property only when the application starts or when the DataContext undergoes a change

`OneWay` updates the target property only when the source property changes.

It's difficult to compare 'efficiency' since they perform different actions.  What are you trying to accomplish with this binding?

Comment: I work with Prism and the MVVM pattern, and for example, I have lots of DelegateCommands in my code which I Bind them with the default mode (OneWay). I want to know if it worth being changed into OneTime mode?